# What are these carpet tiles made of?

Tags: basement, flooring, removal, asbestos, carpet

Underneath basement carpet, I find a layer of 4-inch square carpet tiles.  The underside of these tiles is black with a sandpaper texture.  When removing the tiles, one finds underneath a brittle black layer that is still well adhered to what appears to be the black speckled tile found elsewhere in the basement.  Has anyone worked with these carpet tiles before?  Are they likely to contain asbestos?

[image]

Comment: The only way to know if asbestos is in them is to have them tested.  Even if they contain asbestos a mask is usually enough to protect yourself.  Long term(years) of exposure working with it is the problem.  Short term removing it is usually safe for most people.  Just did a fast google search to see when asbestos was banned.  It seems it is not banned yet in the US so even age cannot be used to help.

Comment: Age in the US can be used for certain *categories* of products, just not 100% for everything. Same for lead - not in regular gas, but still in aviation gas. Not in regular latex house paint, but may be still in some special types.

Comment: How about that dense grainy black layer beneath the carpet; was that some kind of underlayment that is or was used under carpet tiles?